# Rails HAML View: display alongside checkbox and label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, checkbox, haml

I'm working in a View using HAML and Rails, I need to display alongside the checkbox and its label, my closest result is the next:

[image: checkbox]

And this is the code I'm currently using:

```
  %td
    =f.check_box :make_default, class: "checkbox"
    =f.label :make_default, class: "checkbox"
```

As you can see the checkbox and the label are vertically; in case it is useful, the complete code of the form is the next one:

```
  =form_for :document_administration, url: admin_document_administration_path do |f|
    %tr
      %td=f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Add New Document", class: "form-control"
      %td
        =f.check_box :make_default, class: "checkbox"
        =f.label :make_default, class: "checkbox"
      
      %td
        =button_tag( :class => "btn") do
          %span.ix.ix-plus 
          Add
```

My question is: what is the code to display first the checkbox and alongside the label?

Thanks a lot for your time

**UPDATE**:

Following one comment I decided to check column width and height and it is 192.933 x 38; also I decided to remove one column, with that change inside the last cell I have the checkbox+label+button, take a look at this:

[image: object rearranged]

So, it seems by default all objects inside of the cell are in vertical mode; my new question is: what should be the way to change the orientation mode from vertical to horizontal inside the cell?

The code looks like this:

```
  =form_for :program_type, url: admin_program_types_path do |f|
    %tr
      %td=f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Add New Program Type", class: "form-control"
      %td
        =f.check_box :make_default
        =f.label :make_default, class: "checkbox"
        =button_tag( :class => "btn") do
          %span.ix.ix-plus 
          Add
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you remove `class: "checkbox"` from label and try?

Comment: Hi @AbhishekJadav , thanks a lot for your answer; I removed class: "checkbox" just from the label and now the label is always in vertical mode and justify to the bottom of the cell, any other hint?

Comment: probably the <td> that contains the label and checkbox is not wide enough. Look in dev tools and set a wider width to see if the label and checkbox align side-by-side.

Comment: thanks a lot @LesNightingill the width looks good, I've updated the question, all objects inside the cell are in vertical mode, any hints how to change to horizontal?

Comment: in your edit you say that you changed column length. Did you also change the width? What css styling is applied to, or inherited by, the <td> tag?

Comment: sorry @LesNightingill I didn't explain me correctly, I remove a column from the table, I checked my target column's width and height in the devtools and it is: 192.133 x 38. Inside right now I have the checkbox+label+button and this one it is: 192.133 x 98.63. I'm not using CSS in this view

Comment: make the <td> _very_ wide... 1000px, and see if it changes the layout

Comment: if you implement without a table, do the labels/checkboxes align correctly?

Comment: yes, in fact, that was the solution, to get rid of the table, thanks a lot for your time